# iOS - How to find/debug a system function in contacts app

Tags: ios, debugging, facetime

The title might be weird but I try my best to explain my concern.
Upfront: I have little knowledge in programming but I'm willing to learn and understand this whole topic.

I would like to know how I can get an inside look into a function of Apples "Contacts" App or better a function this app provides.

E.G: If you enter a new contact with mobile phone number or email address and you save the inputs, the contacts app automatically responds if this user is able to receive Facetime calls. A new slider appears like a dropdown and you can chose to call via Facetime.

My approach is to have a script where I can enter the number/email and to get a response if Facetime is available or not.

I'm not asking for someone to give my a code example or something. I'm just interested how to approach this task. I would appreaciate if someone can give my a hint in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: It works because Apple has a huge database with every email address and phone number that is registered for FaceTime.  They can check this database for a given email or phone number and return yes/no. This database is not generally accessible

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, that sounds logical and very "ovious". Should've think of that.Well anyway - thank you. :)